# Pandas Groupby: conditional statements within function definition

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

This is my dataframe, df.

```
GAME_DATE_EST   HOME_TEAM         VISITOR_TEAM   HOME_TEAM_WINS
2020-12-18         A                    D                0
2020-12-14         B                    A                0
2020-12-12         C                    A                1
2020-09-11         A                    E                0
```

I want to group by year, and then run a conditional statement that checks whether team A won or lost a match, in a new column, **A Wins**.  For example, if A is a home team, then a value of 0 for **Home Team Wins**, means A lost (0 in **A Wins**).  But if A is a visitor team, then a value of 0 for **Home Team Wins**, means A won (1 in **A Wins**).

Here is my code:

```
df['GAME_DATE_EST'] = pd.to_datetime(df['GAME_DATE_EST'])

def func(row):

   if (row['VISITOR_TEAM'] == 'A') & (row['HOME_TEAM_WINS'] == 0):
      row['A wins'] = 1
   elif (row['HOME_TEAM'] == 'A') & (row['HOME_TEAM_WINS'] == 1):
      row['A wins'] = 1
   else: 
      row['A wins'] = 0

df.groupby(df['GAME_DATE_EST'].dt.year).apply(func)
```

I get this error "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

I've tried resolving this error by specifying `row['HOME_TEAM_WINS'][1]`, but then that gives a key error. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: show your expected result; it will facilitate to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just need to know if team A wins. We can do this in a vectorized way without `if / else`:

```
df['A wins'] = (df.HOME_TEAM.eq('A') & df.HOME_TEAM_WINS.eq(1)) | 
               (df.VISITOR_TEAM.eq('A') & df.HOME_TEAM_WINS.eq(0))

df
#  GAME_DATE_EST HOME_TEAM VISITOR_TEAM  HOME_TEAM_WINS  A wins
#0    2020-12-18         A            D               0   False
#1    2020-12-14         B            A               0    True
#2    2020-12-12         C            A               1   False
#3    2020-09-11         A            E               0   False
```

Also it seems you have a misunderstanding of `groupby` + `apply`. When you `apply` on a GroupBy object, you get a sub data frame as argument to the applied function, not a row, which is why you are getting the [*ValueError*](https://cumsum.wordpress.com/2020/05/29/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-or-a-all/).

Comment: Thank you for an efficient solution.  For my understanding though, how would my code look if I were to use `if / else` ?

Comment: You'll have to use `itertuples` (recommended faster) or `iterrows` to iterrate through rows and build up the list with `if / else`. and then use the list to create a new column. But don't think it will be as efficient as the vectorized solution.